# Riemann Sum of $f(x)=2^x$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

Using Riemann Sums, how can I compute the integral 
$$\int_{0}^{2} 2^x dx$$

I don't know how can I take the Partition and then compute the sums , someone can help to understand this method of Riemann Sums please.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Arturo's answer to this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163096/understanding-riemann-sums should be very helpful.

Comment: Can you spell out your difficulty more clearly. You just divide the interval into $n$ equal parts and form a sum. Is that part clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\;f(x)=2^x\;$ is a continuous function it is Riemann integrable in any bounded interval and thus you can choose that interval's partition *as you like* and **also** the points in each subinterval where the function is going to be evaluated.

Thus, we can choose

$$P:=\left\{x_0=0<x_1=\frac2n<x_2=\frac4n<\ldots<x_k=\frac{2k}n<\ldots<x_n=\frac{2n}n=2\right\}$$

and the points $\;c_k=x_k\in[x_{k-1},x_k]\;$ , and form the Riemann sum

$$\sum_{k=0}^nf(c_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})=\frac2n\sum_{k=0}^n2^{\frac{2k}n}=\frac2n\sum_{k=0}^n\left(4^{1/n}\right)^k=$$

$$=\frac2n\cdot\frac{1-4^{\frac{n+1}n}}{1-4^{1/n}}=\frac2n\cdot\frac{1-e^{\frac{n+1}n\log4}}{1-e^{\frac1n\log4}}$$

Now, observe that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n(1-e^{\frac1n\log4})}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1n}{1-e^{\frac1n\log4}}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-\frac1{n^2}}{\frac{\log4}{n^2}e^{\frac1n\log4}}=-\frac1{\log4}$$

and thus we get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac2n\cdot\frac{1-e^{\frac{n+1}n\log4}}{1-e^{\frac1n\log4}}=-\frac2{\log4}\left(1-4\right)=\frac3{\log2}$$

Checking:

$$\int_0^22^xdx=\left.\frac1{\log2}2^x\right|_0^2=\frac1{\log2}\left(4-1\right)=\frac3{\log2}$$

Comment: Exceptional. +1