# Limit of sum as definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

I don't understand why $$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{n}{n^2+kn+k^2} < \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{n}{n^2+kn+k^2}$$

whereas

$$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{n}{n^2+kn+k^2} > \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{n}{n^2+kn+k^2} $$

I know that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{n}{n^2+kn+k^2}=\dfrac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$$ $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{n}{n^2+kn+k^2}=\dfrac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$$

I saw somewhere on the internet that $$\displaystyle \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f\left(\dfrac{k}{n}\right) > \int_0^1 f(x)dx >  \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} f\left(\dfrac{k}{n}\right)$$ Why is this true?

Comment: Your last inequality should be reversed!! See my answer below.

Comment: Refer also to [Perfect understanding of Riemann Sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2972643/505767) and [Understanding Riemann sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/163096/505767).

Comment: Also see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118515/if-f-is-riemann-integrable-on-0-1-then-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-f/) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x+x^2}$$
and note that the your inequality holds because $f$ is strictly decreasing.

Indeed for $n\geq 1$, $k\geq 0$, and  $x\in [\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}],$ 
$$f(\frac{k}{n})> f(x)> f(\frac{k+1}{n}).$$
By integrating over the interval $[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}]$, we get
$$\frac{f(\frac{k}{n})}{n}=\int_{\frac{k}{n}}^{\frac{k+1}{n}}f(\frac{k}{n})dx> \int_{\frac{k}{n}}^{\frac{k+1}{n}}f(x)dx> \int_{\frac{k}{n}}^{\frac{k+1}{n}}f(\frac{k+1}{n})dx=\frac{f(\frac{k+1}{n}) }{n}.$$
Finally we take the sum for $k=0,\dots,n-1$,
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(\frac{k}{n})>\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx
>\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(\frac{k+1}{n}).$$
Note that the last sum on the right is equal to 
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(\frac{k}{n})=
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(\frac{k}{n})+\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{n}.$$

P.S. Once we have the double inequality, we may conclude that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{n}{n^2+kn+k^2}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{n}{n^2+kn+k^2}=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x+x^2}=\dfrac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}.$$

Comment: Taking n=1 last inequality proves to be correct

Comment: Are you talking about my "last inequality" or yours?

Comment: Yes...............

Comment: @LoopBack Yes what?

Comment: My last inequality is correct for n=1

Comment: Sorry, my fault. You are right!

Comment: I m unable to understand why you have taken x€(k/n , k+1/n)

Comment: And how is $$\frac{f(\frac{k}{n})}{n}=\int_{\frac{k}{n}}^{\frac{k}{n}}f(\frac{k+1}{n})dx$$

Comment: In order to show the inequality I first consider what happens in each subinterval $[k/n,(k+1)/n]$ of $[0,1]$.

Comment: That's a typo, sorry again.

Comment: btw is this expression correct $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{n}{n^2+kn+k^2}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{n}{n^2+kn+k^2}$$

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Finally I understand what you are trying to prove. Actually this result is general. For decreasing functions this is true $$\displaystyle \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(\dfrac{k}{n}) > \int_0^1 f(x)dx > \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(\dfrac{k}{n})$$ whereas this is true for increasing functions $$\displaystyle \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(\dfrac{k}{n}) < \int_0^1 f(x)dx < \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(\dfrac{k}{n})$$ isn't it?

Comment: Yes. they are correct.

Comment: Boo yeah. Thanks a lot. After reading this answer 1000 times. I finally get it

Answer (score 1):

In this case $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x+x^2}$ is decreasing on $[0,\,1]$, so the leftmost expression is the sum of areas of width-$1/n$ rectangles that overestimate the integral, while the rightmost expression is an analogous underestimation with rectangles.